# Python cv2.VideoWriter() produces distorted video when writing .avi from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, video-capture

I'm trying to write out a 3D grayscale f32 numpy array (outputStack) as a video (e.g. .avi, .mp4) in python. However, when I play the video in the default Windows 10 app ("Films & TV") the video plays back highly banded, ugly, and unrecognisable. [image: See image here]

Importantly, my output .avi has the expected dimensions, FPS, and time length. File size is 252,584 KB. Here's my code:

```
(H,W) = np.shape(outputStack[0, :, :])
FPS = 10
seconds = int((np.shape(outputStack[:, 0, 0])[0]) / FPS)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')
titleTemp = './' + fileName.split('.')[0] + '.avi'
vid = cv2.VideoWriter(titleTemp, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), FPS, (W, H), isColor = False)
 
for i in range(FPS * seconds):
    frameTemp = outputStack[i, :, :]
    vid.write(frameTemp)
 
vid.release()
```

I've also tried converting my array to 3-channel BGR using cv2.normalize() and cv2.merge(); here I call cv2.VideoWriter() with isColor = True, which produces similar results. In all cases the frames display fine in matplotlib.

I'm not at all sure what's going wrong. Is it that cv2.VideoWriter doesn't support f32 arrays with 0 to 1 values? Is my codec somehow compressing my array incorrectly? Is it that Windows 10 Films & TV doesn't support the MJPG codec?

Comment: Floating-point videos are not supported as far as I know. You should be using `uint8`.

Comment: Thanks! In my case it's pretty important that I avoid compressing the array. So, I guess I'll just have to accept that VideoWriter() doesn't work for my case. I wrote the array out as a .TIF and converted it to .AVI in ImageJ instead.